# How to combine different textures into one

Tags: uv, texture-baking

Thanks to @moonboots , I managed to edit the textures of our face model for medical research. Now I'd like to combine the base texture with the two additional ones for exporting and sharing the model.
Could someone provide me with a link or a short explanation how I can do that?
Thank's a lot!
[image]

Edit:
I tried Moonboots approach to combine the textures:
[image]

Unfortunately that has as a result that the image of the middle texture is used also as the image for the third texture:

1st spot is working fine:
[image]

That's how the 2nd spot should look like:
[image]

That's how it looks like - same texture as spot 1:
[image]

Is this a problem of UV editting? Once I want to check if the uv maps are positioned correctly, I can't manage to choose the three different ones I've created: spot 1, spot 2, rest. How can i get back to that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix several textures at once, you can only mix 2 by 2. In your case you need to build this kind of setup:

[image]

When you're glad, you can bake everything (but always keep the original setup somewhere in case of problem):

Make sure that you've chosen the *Cycles* render engine, create a new *Image Texture* node, give it a new image (choose its size), keep it selected, go into the *Render* panel > *Bake*, *Bake Type > Diffuse*, under *Influence* disable *Direct* and *Indirect*, click on the *Bake* button. Now you can plug the new *Image Texture* into the *Base Color* input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Comment: That's a great advice, thank you! But as you can see in my screenshot, I've just one additional texture combined to the main texture. Is there a way to combine all three in one step? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fernweh73 oops ok I've edited

Comment: thanks a lot, I edited my post for precision.

Comment: I'm a bit lost, maybe you should tell what images you have and what you're trying to achieve